# What is the right way to wave the lulav and esrog in the down direction?

Tags: minhag, sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

We wave the lulav and esrog (4 minim) in six directions including “down”.

What is the right way to wave down?
I have seen two procedures.

1) The 4 minim are held lower (nearer to the ground) than in the other wavings and waved up and down held vertically three times.

2) The 4 minim are pushed downwards towards the chest and away from the chest, while being held roughly diagonally three times.

Comment: There are many different customs. Which one do you want to know?

Comment: I am interested in all customs where the 4 minim are held in the direction that they grew - not with anything pointing down.

Comment: [Here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30510&pgnum=303) is the Chabad custom. When I get some time I'll make it into an answer (unless someone beats me to it..).

Comment: @Michoel I make that type 2.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3033/759

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Joel M. Finkelstein of Anshei Sphard-Beth El Emeth Synagogue in Memphis can explain it better.

[Video- Rabbi Joel M. Finkelstein](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwLKecpRC6w&feature=relmfu)

Comment: Vezu - it's great - he mentions type 2 shaking.

Comment: Vezu, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing this source! Please consider [edit]ing in a quick summary of what R' Finkelstein says with respect to this question so that people can have an idea of where this answer is going without watching the video.

Comment: Link to the time where he shows it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwLKecpRC6w#t=222s

Answer (score 1):

The Chabad custom (based on the Siddur of the Alter Rebbe, Sefer Haminhagim Chabad and the actual practise of the Lubavitcher Rebbe; collected in [Otzar Minhagei Chabad pg 288](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30510&pgnum=303)) is as follows: each of the six directions comprises of six movements i.e. pushing the four species away and pulling them back towards you three times. Each "pushing" motion starts from the heart, and the "pulling" motion brings back the four species to actually touch the chest in the place we hit when we say *viduy*. The person waving remains standing in one spot facing west and does not turn to the direction he is waving; only his hands and the upper part of his body turns. The lulav remains upright throughout at chest level, besides for the upward and downward waving where the four species remain upright but are elevated to face level or brought downwards. A pictorial guide of this is available [here](http://beta.chabad.org/holidays/JewishNewYear/template_cdo/aid/210033/jewish/Pictorial-Guide.htm).